# Would seq ever be used instead of pseq?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

If `pseq` ensures order of evaluation and `seq` doesn't, why does `seq` exist? Is there any time that `seq` should be used over `pseq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says on the documentation page,

> [pseq] restricts the transformations that the compiler can do, and ensures that the user can retain control of the evaluation order

therefore, if all you need to do is ensure strictness so that you don't get an infinite stack, use `seq`. I don't know of any examples where being able to transform

```
a `seq` b
```

into

```
b `seq` a `seq` b
```

would help performance though, sorry.